# LWC Component when deployed to source not showing on the preview browser

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, javascript, html

[image: output getting] well i'm new in lwc  but whenever i deploy a componant in lwc it get success in status but in preview its not showing proper outpur /rendring output.

```
<lightning-button label="Edit" icon-name="utility:edit"
                 icon-position="left" variant="brand-outline"    
                 ></lightning-button>   

<lightning-button label="Delete" icon-name="utility:delete"
                 icon-position="left" variant="brand-outline"    
                 ></lightning-button>   
                 
<lightning-button label="Log A Call" icon-name="utility:log_a_call"
                 icon-position="left" variant="brand-outline"   
                 ></lightning-button>    
                 
<lightning-button label="Cancel" icon-name="utility:close"
                 icon-position="right" variant="brand-outline"    
                 ></lightning-button>
```

Comment: Are you referring to a Community / Experience Builder preview?